# "JBAS016069: Error injecting persistence unit into CDI managed bean." When deploying WAR with dependency to EJB-JAR

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, wildfly

I have the following setup:

**EJB-JAR:**

- Contains some entities and DAOs.
- Holds the persistence.xml for the EntityManager used in the DAOs.

**Test-WAR:**

- Contains a servlet that injects one of the DAOs of the EJB-JAR (either using @Inject or @EJB).

**The Problem:**

- I am currently deploying the applications to Wildfly 8.x
- When I deploy the jar with a singleton that is started after deployment, I'm able to use the DAOs as intended. I'm getting results from the DB ...
- But when I try to deploy the war with a dependency set to the jar (in MANIFEST.MF or jboss-deployment-structure.xml) I always get the error that Weld cannot inject the persistence unit into the DAO bean since it cannot find the persistence unit with the name I have specified:

  *JBAS016069: Error injecting persistence unit into CDI managed bean. Can't find a persistence unit named test in deployment test.war*

This is a strange error since for the war the container shouldn't need the persistence.xml file because it is located in the ejb-jar where the dao classes are loaded.

So why is the container complaining about that missing persistence unit although it is present in the jar?

---

**Injection of EntityManager (ejb-jar):**

```
public class ShopDAO {
  @PersistenceContext(unitName="test")
  private EntityManager entityManager;
...
```

**persistence.xml (ejb-jar):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="test">
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />
      <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />
      <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer" value="false" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbms:1523:DEV11"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="testuser"/>
      <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="TEST"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Injection of DAO (test-war):**

```
@WebServlet("/status")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
  @Inject
  private ShopDAO shopDAO;

  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //do something with the shop dao!
  }
}
```

**Error log:**

```
    ERROR [fail] MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS016069: Error injecting persistence unit into CDI managed bean. Can't find a persistence unit named test in deployment test.war
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.bootstrap.WeldJpaInjectionServices.getScopedPUName(WeldJpaInjectionServices.java:110)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.bootstrap.WeldJpaInjectionServices.registerPersistenceContextInjectionPoint(WeldJpaInjectionServices.java:73)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory$PersistenceContextResourceInjectionProcessor.getResourceReferenceFactory(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:312)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory$PersistenceContextResourceInjectionProcessor.getResourceReferenceFactory(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:301)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory$ResourceInjectionProcessor.createFieldResourceInjection(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:206)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory$ResourceInjectionProcessor.createResourceInjections(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:182)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory.discoverType(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:405)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory.getResourceInjections(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.<init>(ResourceInjector.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.initInjector(BeanInjectionTarget.java:55)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.<init>(BasicInjectionTarget.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.<init>(BeanInjectionTarget.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.chooseInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:126)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.<init>(ManagedBean.java:91)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.of(ManagedBean.java:71)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.createManagedBean(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:264)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.createClassBean(BeanDeployer.java:248)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$2.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:74)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$2.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Can you include how you are using `@PersistenceContext`, your `persistence.xml` and log?

Comment: What is the `persistence.xml` path? `world.war` and `test-war` are the same thing, right? You use `@PersistenceContext` only in this DAO?

Comment: The war files are the same and I adapted the error log to match the names of the description. @PersistenceContext is only used in the DAO and the persistence.xml lies under ejb-jar/META-INF/. The DAO is also located there and works fine if I use it in another bean within this jar!

Comment: I found out that this behaviour is caused by CDI. If you enable CDI for the ejb-jar with the DAOs in order to inject the DAOs into the Servlet, CDI complains about the missing persistence unit as soon as you set a JBoss-dependency from the war to the jar. The problem is that this dependency is needed in order to have the DAOs on classpath for injection.

Comment: I created a [Weld-Bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-1851) and see what happens. Similar bugs had been closed but I don't the a reason for that.

Comment: I am wondering if this problem has ever been resolved. I am using jboss 7.3 here and I am too running into a similar issue which I have an EAR with JPA and DAOs and whatnots. This EAR deploys fine. But the war that has dependency on this EAR, even though I am not using a direct injection between the two, is giving me a similar error.

Answer (score 1):

I just moved the file **persistence.xml** from "...\src\main\java\META-INF" to "...\src\main\webapp\META-INF" and it worked. The war does not work if in the classes folder there is not META-INF/persistence.xml file.