# jboss-deployment-structure Error injecting persistence unit

Tags: jpa, wildfly, cdi, java-ee-6

First, this is the same problem as [JBAS016069: Error injecting persistence unit into CDI managed bean.” When deploying WAR with dependency to EJB-JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149056/jbas016069-error-injecting-persistence-unit-into-cdi-managed-bean-when-deplo)
But there is no answer there :( and I don't have enough point to comment and my request is not an answer to the problem ; that's why I open a new ticket.

Anyway, I have this jar (let's call it client.jar) that try to use entities/daos defined in another JAR (let's call it modele.jar).
In client.jar, I have this code :

```
public class ImportService implements IServices {
    @EJB(mappedName = "java:global/tab.transmodel/VersionHoraireHome!org.avm.business.transmodel.VersionDAO")
private VersionDAO<VersionHoraire, Integer> vdhDao;
```

In src/main/resources/META-INF I have a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure
xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
    <module name="deployment.modele.jar"/>
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

if the line `<module name="deployment.modele.jar"/>` is commented out then I have the error :

```
(...) 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/avm/business/transmodel/VersionDAO;
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3024)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2205)
at org.jboss.as.server//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:72)
at org.jboss.as.server//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
... 10 more
```

if the line `<module name="deployment.modele.jar"/>` is NOT commented then I have the error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYWELD0037: Error injecting persistence unit into CDI managed bean. Can't find a persistence unit named 'manager' in deployment client.jar for injection point private javax.persistence.EntityManager org.avm.business.transmodel.EquipementHome.entityManager
at org.jboss.as.weld.jpa//org.jboss.as.weld.services.bootstrap.WeldJpaInjectionServices.getScopedPUName(WeldJpaInjectionServices.java:114)
at org.jboss.as.weld.jpa//org.jboss.as.weld.services.bootstrap.WeldJpaInjectionServices.registerPersistenceContextInjectionPoint(WeldJpaInjectionServices.java:77)
at org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory$PersistenceContextResourceInjectionProcessor.getResourceReferenceFactory(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:350)
at org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory$PersistenceContextResourceInjectionProcessor.getResourceReferenceFactory(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:338)
at org.jboss.weld.core//org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory$ResourceInjectionProcessor.createFieldResourceInjection(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:216)
```

And yes, I have a persistence.xml file in modele.jar (src/main/resources/META-INF) which define a persistence unit :

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="manager">
    <jta-data-source>java:/OracleDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />        
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />   
     </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I'm lost :(
If a JEE guru could help, I would appreciate :)

BTW : wildfly11, java1.8, Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a sort of solution...  I generate a client for modele : in the POM I added  :

```
<generateClient>true</generateClient>
    <clientIncludes>
        <clientInclude>modele/dao/*.class</clientInclude>
        <clientInclude>modele/entity/*.class</clientInclude>
    </clientIncludes>
```

In src/main/resources/META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml of the client :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure
xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="deployment.modele-client.jar" />
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

That does the job :)
I wonder what a guru would think about this solution ? Is it THE correct way to do ?